# Can you select multiple players in a command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When you use a command like this:

```
/effect Tisajokt 1 30 1
```

You can give the IGN Tisajokt speed. Is there any way to list off multiple people in a command like the above, without scoreboard objectives?

Comment: You know about `@a` and `@p`, right?  I'm assuming that since you mentioned scoreboard objectives.

Comment: @MBraedley Of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't. You can only filter the list of players by certain criteria when using the `@a` selector. The ways in which you can filter are by position (including radius), min/maxscoreboard objective scored, having a certain item, min/max experience level, game mode or team.

[See the wiki for a full description of each filter](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block#Arguments).

If there are two *specific, named* players you want to target, just use two command blocks.

Answer (score 0):

There is one other way of doing this besides using Scoreboard. In 1.9 there was a new data tag introduced called a tag. If you tag the players or entities you want to get this effect, use the ! Selector with this tag to select everything you do not want to get this speed effect. If you need to know how to do this, I believe Dragnoz made a video about it on YouTube.